# How to write a topLayoutGuide constraint in VFL

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm learning to write constraints in VFL from code

I have centered my view horizontally like that:

```
let constraintY = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:[superview]-(<=1)-[collaboratorView]",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY,
            metrics: nil,
            views: ["superview":self.assetsView, "collaboratorView":collaboratorView])
```

but i wondering how to write constraint to topLayoutGuide
that looks in storyboard like that
[image]

I've ended up with something like this, but its doesn't work ;(

```
let bar = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|[collaboratorView]",
            options: [NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllTop],
            metrics: nil,
            views: ["collaboratorView":self.collaboratorView])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define as below:

```
let views : [String : AnyObject] = ["collaboratorView": collaboratorView,
  "topLayoutGuide": topLayoutGuide,
  "bottomLayoutGuide": bottomLayoutGuide]

// 2
var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

// 3
let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[collaboratorView]-12-[topLayoutGuide]",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: views)
allConstraints += verticalConstraints
```

Comment: thank you a lot, just one more question

I was always wondering what if the topLayoutGuide here :  "topLayoutGuide": topLayoutGuide,
could you add implementation to your answer please ?

Comment: Implement it and you will see what is it. This is a defined property in UIViewController,

Comment: oh, i missed that i'm inside UIView, your answer is correct anyway ;)